# How do I make a C# script in Unity?

Tags: unity

I was watching a tutorial on how to script, and I got stuck making the script in the first place. I use Unity 2019.3.0a5

Comment: Note that [this is the very first Google result](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CreatingAndUsingScripts.html) for "[make c# script unity](https://www.google.com/search?q=make+c%23+script+unity)", so please remember to search for your question first: it's much faster than waiting for someone to type-up info that's already at your fingertips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## From Game Object

1. Create a game object or use an existing one.
2. Go to the inspector (panel on the right side).
3. Click on "Add Component", it will open a small pop up.
4. The last option is called "New Script". Click that. You can also write "New Script" on the search bar or just write the name of your new script. If that name doesn't exist, Unity will ask you to if you want to make a new script.

[image]

## From Hierarchy folder

1. Press secondary click on the bottom panel (folder views).
2. Click create.
3. Click C# Script (old versions [as fair I know] allowed you to make UnityScript, Boo Script or Javascript).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. create (eg) a empty Game Object
2. look at its inspector
3. click on "Add Component"
4. New Script

Hope this helped. :p